# Part of a proof for $(1 + 1/x)^x < e < (1 + 1/x)^{x+1}$ for $1 \leq x$

Tags: calculus

I'm reading a text that says

$x \ln ( 1 + 1/x ) < 1 < (x+1) \ln ( 1 + 1/ x)$

Can be written as

$\frac{1}{x+1} < \ln(1+1/x) < 1/x$

However I'm not making much headway making this connection. For example, I don't see how we ended up with a logarithm on the inside but no nested logarithms on the outside.

Comment: Split the first chained inequalities into two separate inequalities.

Comment: $ab<1<cb$ for positive $a,b,c$ implies ${1\over c}<b<{1\over a}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x>0$ then we can divide through by $\ln(1+\frac 1x)$

$x < \frac {1}{\ln(1+\frac 1x)} < x+1$

Now if we take the reciprocal of each term it is going to flip the direction of the inequalities.

$\frac 1x > \ln(1+\frac 1x) > \frac 1{x+1}$

Comment: Thank you. I probably should have been able to see this but makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach:

$\displaystyle I = \ln\left( ~1 + ~\frac{1}{x} ~\right) = 
\ln\left( ~\frac{x+1}{x} ~\right) = \ln(x+1) - \ln(x) = \int_x^{x+1} \frac{1}{t} \,dt.$

Now, consider the area under the curve, from $~x~$ to $~x+1,~$ of the function $~f(t) = \dfrac{1}{t}.~$ 
$~I~$ equals this area.

Now consider two rectangles, each of width 1, delineated as follows:

- Lower left hand corner is $~(x,0),~$ upper right hand corner is $~\left( ~x+1,\dfrac{1}{x} ~\right).~$ 
  This is the tall rectangle, whose area is $~1 \times \dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{1}{x}.~$ 
  This tall rectangle completely covers the region represented by the integral $~I.~$
- Lower left hand corner is $~(x,0),~$ upper right hand corner is $~\left( ~x+1,\dfrac{1}{x+1} ~\right).~$ 
  This is the short rectangle, whose area is $~1 \times \dfrac{1}{x+1} = \dfrac{1}{x+1}.~$ 
  This short rectangle is completely covered by the region represented by the integral $~I.~$

Therefore 
The area of the tall rectangle $~> I > ~$ the area of the short rectangle.

Therefore 
$~\displaystyle \frac{1}{x} > \ln\left( ~1 + \frac{1}{x} ~\right) > \frac{1}{x+1}.$

Comment: That's creative and fun, thank you